# Using enum in selectOneMenu fails with: 'Male' must be convertible to an enum

Tags: jsf, enums, selectonemenu

I am about developing a small jsf project and I arrived to a state that I have to store a value in an enumeration type but couldn't figure out how to deal with

so I post here a small description of my problem:

here is the enumeration type:

```
 package com.enumeration;

 import java.io.Serializable;


 public enum Gender implements Serializable{

    Male('M'), Female('F');

    private char description;

   private Gender(char description) {
     this.description = description;
   }

   public char getDescription() {
     return description;
   }
```

}

the xhtml page:

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Nom:" for="nom" />
                <h:inputText id="nom" value="#{employee.newEmployee.nom}" title="Nom" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Gender:" for="gender" />
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{employeeBean.newEmployee.gender}" id="gender">
                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="Male" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="Female"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>

            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value="ajouter" action="index.xhtml" actionListener="#{employeeBean.ajouter}" />
        </h:form>
```

the problem is that when I try to add a new row to the database, and error is thrown by jsf:  **j_idt7:gender: 'Male' must be convertible to an enum.**

I did some search on the net but couldn't understand the solutions
please help
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that your `<f:selectItem>` specify strings, while in the `<h:selectItem value="#{employeeBean.newEmployee.gender}">` seems to return one of the two `Gender` enums.

Enums are AFAIK directly convertible without converter as long as you stick the same values into both.

Here's the/a pattern:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{employeeBean.newEmployee.gender}" id="gender">
    <f:selectItems value="#{enumValuesProvider.genders}"
                   var="gender"
                   itemValue="#{gender}"
                   itemLabel="#{gender.name()}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Note, I'm using `<f:selectItems>` here. The problem is, you can't simply get the values from a JSF page directly. You will need a dedicated bean to do the job:

```
@Named      // or @ManagedBean if you're not using CDI
@ViewScoped // or @RequestScoped
public EnumValuesProvider implements Serializable
{
    public Gender[] getGenders()
    {
        return Gender.values();
    }
}
```

This is just written down without any testing. No warranties.

Comment: hi thanks for help,
i did as follows  
<h:outputLabel value="Gender:" for="gender" />
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{employeeBean.newEmployee.gender}" id="gender">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{employeeBean.genders}"
                                       var="gender"
                                       itemValue="#{gender.description}"
                                       itemLabel="#{gender}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>

and i gt the error "j_idt20:gender: 'F' must be convertible to an enum. "

Comment: probably you have an "Select" item with null value, or something like that

Answer (score 0):

**In my entity:**

```
@Entity

public class MyClass {
@Column
@Convert(converter = MyEnumConverter.class)
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private MyEnumType myEnumType;
//....getter and setter    }
```

---

**In my enum:**

```
public enum MyEnumType {
    AAAA,
    BBBB;
public String getLabel() {
    switch (this) {
        case AAAA:
            return "aaaa";
        case BBBB:
            return "bbbb";

    }
    return "NONE";
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getLabel();
}
}
```

**another enum:**

```
public enum AnotherEnum {
      ...
}
```

---

**In my convertor:**(It is not one FacesConvertor).

```
@Converter
public class MyEnumConvertor implements AttributeConverter<MyEnumType, Byte> {
    @Override
    public Byte convertToDatabaseColumn(MyEnumType attribute) {
        switch (attribute) {
            case AAAA:
                return 0;
            case BBBB:
                return 1;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown" + attribute);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public MyEnumType convertToEntityAttribute(Byte dbData) {
        switch (dbData) {
            case 0 :
                return EstatePossessionType.AAAA;
            case 1:
                return EstatePossessionType.BBBB;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown" + dbData);
        }
    }
  }
```

---

**In my util class:**

```
public class MyUtilClass {
    public <T extends Enum> SelectItem[]     createSelectItemByEnumClass(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        SelectItem[] selectItem = null;
        int i = 0;
        try {
          Object[] enumConstants = clazz.getEnumConstants();
            if (enumConstants != null) {
                selectItem = new SelectItem[enumConstants.length];
                for (Object object : enumConstants) {
                    selectItem[i++] = new SelectItem(object,     object.toString());
              }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return selectItem;
    }
}
```

---

**In my CDI-bean class:**

```
public class MyCdiClass {
    MyEnumType selectByUser = null;
    public Class getSelectItemClass(){
        return MyEnumType.class;//<<--I'll tell jsf, I want create SelectItem from this class.Maybe I have more than one enum:).
    }
    public MyEnumType getSelectByUser() {
        return selectByUser;
    }
    public void setSelectByUser(MyEnumType selectByUser) {
        this.selectByUser = selectByUser;
    }
}
```

---

**In my jsf page:**

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{handleEstateActionInEstate.selectByUser}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myUtility.createSelectItemByEnumClass(myCdiBean.selectItemClass)}"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

I hope these snippet be useful.